# find the percentage in SQL aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum, percentage

I have a table cashback with column userid, and category of cashback like "Food", "Departmental",etc
I want count of category of cashback per userid
so I have used COUNT(cashback.report_store_categoryname) as Total_AOV
now want to percentage of it also
SO I have used Total_AOV*100/SUM(Total_AOV)

```
SELECT 
  cashback.userid, COUNT(cashback.report_store_categoryname) as Total_AOV,
  CAST(CASE WHEN Total_AOV*100/SUM(Total_AOV)>50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) as per
FROM cashback
WHERE cashback_status = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY cashback.userid
LIMIT 10;
```

But this is giving me an error

> OUTPUT: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or
> window function

Comment: You can't reference Total_AOV in the same SELECT list as it is defined.

Comment: How the parser should know, that you need to sum up `Total_AOV` over all the rows, but not in the context of `group by`?

Comment: Might want to tag your DBMS, since your query as is will result in a syntax error in at least MSSQL (and i'd assume others). Not even producing your aggregate function error. Also it's unclear to me what you actually want to achieve with your cast/case statements, because you won't get a percentage out of it. That's for sure.

Comment: then how can I get it

Comment: Suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

In pure standard ISO SQL, this could be write:

```
SELECT 
  cashback.userid, COUNT(cashback.report_store_categoryname) as Total_AOV,
  CAST(CASE WHEN (COUNT(cashback.report_store_categoryname))*100/SUM(COUNT(cashback.report_store_categoryname)) OVER()>50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) as per
FROM cashback
WHERE cashback_status = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY cashback.userid
```

Comment: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported

Comment: using in windows

Comment: You do not give us what DBMS you use. This works fine over most of the RDBMS !

Comment: `per` as an ISO SQL reserved word, i.e. must be delimited as `"per"` if used as identifier. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words) Otherwise the syntax is fine.